# Ajax call on $.ajax().complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with jQuery ajax function. I working with API that provides users and RBAC managment. By design this is separated functions, so when i create a user and assign a role for it i should call two requests - first i send 'create user' and it's return a {"success":"true", "id":"[id nuber]"} then i send 'assign role' with params like "{"item":"RoleName", "user_id":"[id from previous request]"}".
There is object "api" which have some methods for work with API. It is a simple wrapper which knocking on www.myurl.api/ and returns json. Because of it may take a long time api object methods takes a handlers that will be run on success and fail. If api now running a request then api.ready == false, otherwise api.aready == true. Result of last request stored in api.data as object.

Problem is that result not saved in api.data in case when two API request cascaded, like:

```
api.send(params, //params is json for user creation
    function(){  //handler on this request result
        ...      //creating another parms for assignment from api.data
        api.send(params2, function(){//handler that works if api coorectly creates a new user
            ... //here i try send a request with params and it fails  
        })
}

);
```

code of api.send method:

```
send: function (entity, request, params, method, handler){
    if (!method)
        method='POST';
    if (request.toLowerCase()=='get')
        request = '';
    if (request)
        request += '-';
    api.data = null;
    params.apiKey = api.key;
    api.ready = false;
    api.handler = handler;
    $.ajax({
        url: this.url+request+ entity,
        method: 'GET',
        data: params
    }).complete(function(msg) {
      api.data = JSON.parse(msg.responseText);
      if (api.data[0] && api.data[0].meta)
          api.data.forEach(function (element, index, array){
              element.meta = JSON.parse(element.meta)
          });
      api.ready = true;
      api.handler.call();
    });
}
```

and this is function that calls to create new user

```
function createUser(){
    validateCreateForm();
    if (!createValidated )
        return;
    var values = {
      "username": $('#inputUsername').val(),
      "password": $('#inputPassword').val(),
      "comment": "Added by "+adderUsername
    };

    api.send('users','add', values, 'POST', function () {
        if (api.data.success="true"){

//===========all in this if works ONLY if api works succesfully
//===========and api.data.id is exist and correct

            message("success", "Was created username " + values.username);
            $('#inputUsername').val('');
            $('#inputPassword').val('');

 //==========Problem is here
            id = api.data.id; //in this var stores id
            console.log('api.data.id is ' + id);//undefined, should be some int.
 //if write something like id=42 rights will be correcttly assigned for user with id 42 
 //================================================================

            if (!$('#inputRole').val())
               return;
            api.send('assignments',
                     'add',
                     {
                       "user_id": id,
                       "item_name": $('#inputRole').val()
                     },
                      'POST',
                      function () {
                          if (api.data.success="true"){
                              message("success", "Account was created and permissions granted");
                          }
                          else {
                              message("success", "Inner error. Please, try again later.");
                          }
                      }
                    );
        }
        else {
            message("danger", "Inner error. Please, try again later.");

    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you expect the wrong data in `.complete` - almost as if you should be using `.done`

Comment: 2 things - `complete` fires regardless, `success` fires if you get a `200 status code`. Since ajax is also `async`, and you stated that your "api could take awhile`, either set `async: false` in the options for `ajax`, OR initiate a callback function

Comment: Thanks, guys! Both comments helps. Rob's comment completly solve issue